# MYSQL Query for similiar data in multiple columns

Tags: mysql

```
+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+
| contactID | fullname | firstname | lastname |
+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+
| c01       | Ash Das  | ASH       | Das      |
| c02       | Abhi Das | Abhi      | Das      |
| c01       | Ash Das  | Ash       | AH       |
+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+
```

From the above table I need to write a query which will provide similar names from the table. It can match frstname, lastname as well as fullname.

Comment: That's great. Welcome to SO.

Comment: I can see you're new here...usually people will provide some code that they are struggling with or at least an example of what they've tried, or bare minimum what they expect to get etc, etc. You question is very vague and doesn't show any of the above. Also, I don't see why you would need a fullname field when you have firstname and lastname....I guess there is probably a reason but this is the sort of thing you need to explain to us.

Answer (score 0):

You may with the soundex function but be advised than performances will not be optimal because indexes can't be used by mysql server with that kind of string functions.

For example if you look only by fullname

```
select c1.contactID,c1.fullname, c2.contactID, c2.fullname
from <contacttable> c1
inner join <contacttable> c2 on 
    (c1.contactId != c2.contactId AND soundex(c1.fullname) = soundex(c2.fullname))
```